# Normal Black-Scholes model for swaptions isn't working properly

Tags: black-scholes, fixed-income, normal-distribution, swaption, lognormal

I just wrote two functions in Matlab which calculates the swaption prices based on the Lognormal model and on the Normal model, although I have the idea that the Normal model is wrong because the swaption price is (I think) too high.

Hereby the Lognormal function in Matlab:

```
 function [Receiver, Payer] = BlackSwaptionModel(K,S,Bvol,Time,Reonia,TenorSwap)
        d1 = (log(S/K) + 1/2*Bvol^2*Time) / (Bvol*sqrt(Time));
        d2 = d1 - (Bvol * sqrt(Time));

        Receiver = ((1-1/(1+S)^(TenorSwap)) / S) * exp(-Reonia*Time) * (S*normcdf(d1) - K*normcdf(d2)); %Value receiver swaption Black Model
        Payer = ((1-1/(1+S)^(TenorSwap)) / S) * exp(-Reonia*Time) * (K*normcdf(-d2) - S*normcdf(-d1)); % Value payer swaption Black Model
      end
```

Plus the Normal model function in Matlab:

```
function [Receiver, Payer] = NormalSwaptionModel(K,S,Nvol,Time,Reonia,TenorSwap)

    d1 = (S-K) / (Nvol * sqrt(Time));
    d2 = -(S-K) / (Nvol * sqrt(Time));

    Receiver = Nvol * sqrt(Time) * (d1*normcdf(d1) + normpdf(d1)) * ((1-1/(1+S)^(TenorSwap)) / S) * exp(-Reonia*Time);

    Payer = Nvol * sqrt(Time) * (d2*normcdf(d2) + normpdf(d2)) * ((1-1/(1+S)^(TenorSwap)) / S) * exp(-Reonia*Time);

end
```

Could anybody see what's going wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: what are your input parameters?

Comment: And where did you get your forumlas?

Comment: Input parameterrs are: S = 0.02, K=0.02, Reonia=0.01, Time=1, Bvol=0.20, Nvol=0.20,Tenorswap=10. Now I know that when using these parameters the two formula's won't yield the same value but I think there is something wrong with the NormalSwaptionModel because the Nvol needs to be very small (which doesn't make sense) will these formula's give the same value for the swaptions.

Comment: The vols do not have the same order of magnitude. To get an idea, at the money, a 30% lognormal vol can correspond to a 0.60% normal vol. Normal vols are usually quoted in bps = 0.01%.

Comment: Hereby the link of the article: http://www.milliman.com/insight/2015/The-new-normal-Using-the-right-volatility-quote-in-times-of-low-interest-rates-for-Solvency-II-risk-factor-modelling/

Comment: What do you exactly mean with the same order of magnitude. So for example if the Black vol = 30% -> 0.30 as an input Normalvol will be for example 0.60% so meaning 0.0060 as an input for the model?

Answer (score 1):

> The vols do not have the same order of magnitude. To get an idea, at the money, a 30% lognormal vol can correspond to a 0.60% normal vol. Normal vols are usually quoted in bps = 0.01%.

The approximate relation should be

Nvol = S * Bvol

If you want to be more accurate, you can invert the price obtained from the BS model into the normal implied volatility. See here for direct approximation https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/32489/26559 .

Comment: very good point and very important in quoting swaption volas!